# Having to declare javascript variables inside of functions after declaring them in scoping functions

Tags: javascript, function, scope, global-variables

I find that in order to get my code to work I am having to declare all(or at least 80%) of my variables and instantiate them locally even though I have already done so within a scoping function...why is this? For instance:

```
$(function() {
  var cUnit, fUnit, temp, wind, humidity, weatherDescrpt, wData;
  cUnit = true;
  fUnit = false;

  $("#fUnit").click(function() {
    var cUnit = true;
    var fUnit = false;
    toggleTemp(cUnit,fUnit);
  });

  function setAttribute(wData) {
    cUnit = true;
    fUnit = false;
    temp = displayTemp(wData.main.temp,fUnit);
  }
});
```

UPDATE---
I believe I have finally found the issue...too many if statements in toggleTemp()..things seem good to go now

Comment: The code you are showing wouldn't need the locally set variables, [works here](https://jsfiddle.net/45uhz1ee/). You probably have some other code that is causing the problem. Show more of your actual code, and maybe provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which is the part that doesn't work without local variables? Nothing in the code shown calls your `setAttribute()` function, but that function is the only place that tries to use the variables from the outer function. Can you please [edit] your question to show a self-contained example of something that you think should work but doesn't, and include a couple of comments in the code to point out which line(s) are going wrong?

Comment: @Patrick &@nnnnnn...My apologies, I am new to stack and wasn't sure if was allowed to place "too much" of the code..I will amend my question to hopefully show where I think it's going wrong...additionally I have inputted some of your suggestions so I am getting some of the desired functionality but not all

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have shown, you do in fact need absolutely no local variables (with the exception of the `wData` parameter):

```
$(function() {
  $("#fUnit").click(function() {
    toggleTemp(true, false);
  });

  function setAttribute(wData) { // looks like dead code that is called from nowhere
    displayTemp(wData.main.temp, false);
  }
});
```

Of course you can (and possibly should) factor out those constants in local variables. But then, you would *only* declare and assign them in your module scope, nowhere else:

```
$(function() {
  const cUnit = true;
  const fUnit = false;
  $("#fUnit").click(function() {
    toggleTemp(cUnit, fUnit);
  });

  function setAttribute(wData) {
    displayTemp(wData.main.temp, fUnit);
  }
});
```